# New to Java, learning quick, but can't figure out why my for loops wont print

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
public class poundtokilogram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Kilograms     Pounds   |   Pounds     Kilograms");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

    int kilos = 1;
    int pounds = 20;

    for ( kilos = 1; kilos > 200; kilos++ ) {
        for ( pounds = 20; pounds > 515; pounds++) {
            double kiloc = pounds * .453;
            double poundc = kilos * 2.2;
            System.out.print(kilos + "    " + poundc + " | " + pounds + "     " + kiloc + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here's the code, essentially I'm trying to print out a conversion chart with kilograms to pounds on one side and pounds to kilograms on the other (it's just an exercise in a book I'm learning from) and for some reason when I go to run this it will only print out the first two lines. BTW, first time posting to StackOverflow, suggestions on how to be more clear would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to step through the code in debugger? Nambi has given the correct answer below but learning to use debugger will help you in future as well

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please dont forget to upvote the answer you found helpful  and accept the answer that really answered your question the most by clicking the up arrow and check mark in the upper left side of an answer.

Comment: Honestly I'm not completely sure how to do this in the first place. Using Eclipse btw, but I'm pretty new to working with Java so a lot of common sense kind of stuff doesn't occur to me.

Comment: Minor topic: Class names should start with an uppercase letter :) Poundtokilogram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are checking `kilos` are greater than 200 and pounds greater than 515

change this

```
for ( kilos = 1; kilos > 200; kilos++ ) { 
for ( pounds = 20; pounds > 515; pounds++) {
```

to

```
for ( kilos = 1; kilos < 200; kilos++ )
for ( pounds = 20; pounds < 515; pounds++) {
```

Comment: Wow do I feel stupid, I guess I've been starring at this screen for too long if I'm not noticing that stuff XD. Thanks man1

Comment: @XechaTigs It's Ok dude

Answer (score 2):

Your outer loop is not even starting because the condition is that `kilos` must be greater than 200. I suppose you want to say: `kilos < 200`

Also, in the inner loop you have `pounds > 515` but you are not modifying pounds before the condition is evaluated. Change the condition to `pounds < 515` (that is what I think you want to execute)

Comment: Yeah those two simple tweaks did it.